# How to call the function that accepts std::istream&

Tags: c++, list, input, istream

I am a beginner in C++. What is the correct way to call a function that expects `std::istream&`?

Tried it with `read(std::cin);`, but I get an error from the compiler.

```
typedef double Element;

template<typename T>
std::list<T> read(std::istream& i) {  
  Element input;
  std::list<Element> l;
  while(i>>input) {
   l.push_back(input);
  }
  return l;
}
```

Comment: And the error from your compiler is what, exactly? And the code that calls this function is what, exactly? It's probably has nothing to do, whatsoever, with `std::istream`, but with the fact that the template parameter is not deducible here, but can't say for sure without seeing the code.  Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: no matching function for call to 'read' is the error I got

Comment: And the error message continues: `note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'`. What should a compiler substitute for `T` when you write `read(std::cin)`?

Comment: It should substitute Element so the type is double

Comment: Thank you very much !!! read<type>(std::cin) solved my problem

Comment: Alternative solution: `template<typename T = Element>`. But anyway, you should not mix `Element` and `T` inside `read()`. It should be either `Element` (and then `read()` would become a regular function) or `T` (and then it should be `std::list<T> l;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to the `std::istream&` parameter.

The issue is that the function is a function template that requires an explicit template argument determining the type that is supposed to be read from the stream, e.g.:

```
read<int>(std::cin)
```

The error message from the compiler should be telling you something like that as well.

That aside, you are then not using `T` in the function. Probably you wanted to replace all uses of `Element` by `T` and remove the `typedef`.

Answer (score -2):

you have just a small syntax error:

try this code :

```
typedef double Element;
class test{

public:
auto read(std::istream& i){

Element input;
std::list<Element> l;
while(i>>input){
 l.push_back(input);
}
return l;
}


};


int main(){
test t;
t.read(std::cin);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP has `template<typename T>`, but you don't

Comment: And it doesn't make much sense to put a function into a class.

Comment: He could have a class of many member functions and he ask the question about one function.
This does not mean that I told him to use a class, and you can replace auto with std::list<T> ok. @justANewbie